# How to allocate more memory for a variable

Tags: c#, memory, console-application, windows-ce

I have created a c# program that takes a scan input, and then takes the information from the input. What I have been noticing is that for larger strings, my program for some reason splits the string into two parts (not in half), which screws up the way I get my information. My string has hexadecimal values in it as well.

For example, when I scan a code into my console, it reads the string

```
[)>065JUN1234567892300167Q205GT21L123 ABC06P123456787Q100PL7Q10PKQ1006P98356877Q100PL7Q5PKQ2006P235265437Q200PL7Q40PKQ5
```

but it splits that string into:

```
[)>065JUN1234567892300167Q205GT21L123 ABC06P123456787Q100PL7Q10PKQ1006P98356877Q100"
```

and

```
PL7Q5PKQ2006P235265437Q200PL7Q40PKQ5
```

Any idea how to fix this, or allocate more memory to my variable which reads the console for the input scan?

Here is my code, its kind of long.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date and lane number");
        Console.WriteLine("like so: ddmmyylanenumber.");
        string lanenum = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("When done scanning, please type");
        Console.WriteLine("\"finish\" into the console.");
        string scanInput;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Scan now:");
            scanInput = Console.ReadLine();

                //The number before "JUN" identifies the type of label it is.
                int posOfJUN = scanInput.IndexOf("JUN");
                //Finding the type of label
                string typeOfLabel = scanInput.Substring(posOfJUN - 1, 1);
                string label;
                if (typeOfLabel == "5")
                {
                    label = "mixed";
                }
                else if (typeOfLabel == "1")
                {
                    label = "individual";
                }
                else
                {
                    label = null;
                }

                switch (label)
                {
                    case "individual":
                        partNumber = scanInput.Substring(8, 8);

                        int posOfQ1 = scanInput.IndexOf("Q");
                        int posOf1JUN = scanInput.IndexOf("1JUN");
                        //Quantity of the pack
                        total = scanInput.Substring(posOfQ1 + 1, posOf1JUN - posOfQ1 - 1 - 1);
                        //number of packs is 1 because individual
                        numOfPacks = "1";
                        dunsNumber = scanInput.Substring(posOf1JUN + 4, 9);
                        //used to find the duns and serial number
                        posOf20L = scanInput.IndexOf("20L");
                        posOf21L = scanInput.IndexOf("21L");

                        //Setting the serial number
                        if (posOf21L == -1 || posOf20L < posOf21L)
                        {
                            serialNumber = scanInput.Substring(posOf1JUN + 4, posOf20L - posOf1JUN - 4 - 1);
                        }
                        else if (posOf20L == -1 || posOf21L < posOf20L)
                        {
                            serialNumber = scanInput.Substring(posOf1JUN + 4, posOf21L - posOf1JUN - 4 - 2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            serialNumber = null; //else clause if serial number can't be created
                            Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentException("Error obtaining Serial Number"));
                        }

                        partObject part2 = new partObject(partNumber, total, numOfPacks);

                        newPacks = int.Parse(numOfPacks);
                        total = total.ToString();
                        newtotal = int.Parse(total);
                        part2.callSQL(partNumber, newtotal, newPacks, dunsNumber, serialNumber, lanenum);
                        break;

                    case "mixed":
                        posOfJUN = scanInput.IndexOf("JUN");
                        dunsNumber = scanInput.Substring(posOfJUN + 3, 9);
                        int posOf7Q = scanInput.IndexOf("7Q");
                        posOf20L = scanInput.IndexOf("20L");
                        posOf21L = scanInput.IndexOf("21L");

                        //Finding serial number
                        serialNumber = scanInput.Substring(posOfJUN + 3, posOf7Q - posOfJUN - 3);

                        //The following lines are to find how many different parts are in the mixed load. 
                        posOfPK = scanInput.IndexOf("PK");
                        int PKTemp;
                        int parts = 1;
                        //Each time a "PK" is seen, it means there is another part so the count increments.
                        while (scanInput.IndexOf("PK", posOfPK + 1) != -1)
                        {
                            PKTemp = scanInput.IndexOf("PK", posOfPK + 1);
                            posOfPK = PKTemp;
                            parts++;
                        }
                        //Creating an array of size "parts"
                        int posOf06 = scanInput.IndexOf("06");
                        int temp06 = scanInput.IndexOf("06", posOf06 + 2);
                        posOf06 = temp06;
                        int indexOfP = scanInput.IndexOf("P", posOf06 + 1);
                        partNumber = scanInput.Substring(indexOfP + 1, 8);

                        posOfPK = scanInput.IndexOf("PK", indexOfP);
                        posOfPL = scanInput.IndexOf("PL", indexOfP);
                        posOf7Q1 = scanInput.IndexOf("7Q", indexOfP);
                        partObject[] arrayOfParts = new partObject[parts];

                        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
                        {

                            //Finds the different values, creates an object and puts it into the array of parts
                            partNumber = scanInput.Substring(indexOfP + 1, 8);
                            total = scanInput.Substring(posOf7Q1 + 2, posOfPL - posOf7Q1 - 2);
                            numOfPacks = scanInput.Substring(posOfPL + 5, posOfPK - posOfPL - 5);
                            arrayOfParts[i] = new partObject(partNumber, total, numOfPacks);

                            //resetting the variables for the next iteration, so a new object can be created with the next part
                            posOf06 = scanInput.IndexOf("06", temp06 + 1);
                            indexOfP = scanInput.IndexOf("P", posOf06 + 1);
                            temp06 = posOf06;
                            posOfPK = scanInput.IndexOf("PK", indexOfP);
                            posOfPL = scanInput.IndexOf("PL", indexOfP);
                            posOf7Q1 = scanInput.IndexOf("7Q", indexOfP);

                            //putting each object into SQL
                            newtotal = int.Parse(total);
                            newPacks = int.Parse(numOfPacks);
                            serialNumber = serialNumber + "P" + (i + 1);
                            arrayOfParts[i].callSQL(partNumber, newtotal, newPacks, dunsNumber, serialNumber, lanenum);

                        }


                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        } while (scanInput != "finish");
    }
```

The full string is never there right from the start of the code.

Comment: It's not an issue of memory, that string is small.  The issue is how you are reading it in.  Post your code.

Comment: splits how? c# isn't going to give you two strings when you only asked for one.

Comment: @Mark Hey I have added my code, thought that it was an issue of memory which is why I didn't include it, my bad.

Comment: The length of the substring that you are getting is 80 characters. The default console width in windows is 80 characters. Is this coincidence? How are you entering this data into the console? My suspicion is that you are providing faulty input (inadvertantly) that includes a newline.

Comment: You're right, that is a lot of code. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? With sample input data, definitely.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your program I think you will find that the `string` is all there.
I'm not sure why you think the `string` is `split`... a `System.String` can only hold one `string`. At some point are you getting a `string[]` ?

Place a breakpoint after this line `scanInput = Console.ReadLine();` and in Visual Studio hover over `scanInput`, and it will show you the whole string.... or try just printing out the string to show that it is all there.

EDIT: If you're using hexadecimal, try looking up the hex values which cause the anomaly on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Perhaps the hex value is resulting in a carriage return or newline.

Comment: I just added a breakpoint to my 'Console.ReadLine()' and the string there is different from whats being inputted into the console. My string has hexadecimal values in it, you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of this. it may be possible that the console it misinterpreting these values as console directives.

Comment: @AlvinJ a `String` *can't* have hex values, only `Char`. Are you *typing* the string, or is it input via redirection?

Comment: @crashmstr No I'm not typing the string, I scan a barcode which contains hex values in it, and it gets printed into the console and then entered into the program.

Comment: @AlvinJ try changing to use `Read`, and see what you are getting. Sounds like it is something with how the input is coming in and how `Readline` is interpreting it.

Comment: @crashmstr is it always the same hex value? If so, can you post it.

Comment: @AlvinJ, as suggested in the comments of your question, could it be the way you're copying and pasting the text? Try changing the number of columns in the console to accommodate the text in one line only